# ensure visible on android listview?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

Is there a way that I can makle sure a given item in an android listview is entirely visible?

I'd like to be able to programmatically scroll to a specific item, like when I press a button for example.

Answer (score 20):

[`ListView.setSelection()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29) will scroll the list so that the desired item is within the viewport.

Comment: Setselection scrolls it to top of the view. I just need it to move as little as possible

Comment: This answer is not accurate, as CodeFusionMobile pointed out. Thus I wouldn't really accept it... :-(

Answer (score 11):

Try it:

```
public static void ensureVisible(ListView listView, int pos)
{
    if (listView == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(pos < 0 || pos >= listView.getCount())
    {
        return;
    }

    int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();

    if (pos < first)
    {
        listView.setSelection(pos);
        return;
    }

    if (pos >= last)
    {
        listView.setSelection(1 + pos - (last - first));
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: listView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos); instead of setSelection(...) if you want. Thanks jauseg.

Comment: Hmm. There's at least one pitfall here: in case you setup the selection before layout has been done - there will be no last visible position (=-1) and everything breaks. You need to make sure this is run AFTER the layout is done. Otherwise it does not work as expected but sets the selection completely wrong.

Comment: Not working in case of Listview inside a custom Dialog. Please suggest.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you are looking for is [ListView.setSelectionFromTop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelectionFromTop%28int,%20int%29) (although I'm a bit late to the party).

Answer (score 3):

Recently I met the same problem, paste my solution here in case someone need it (I was trying to make the entire last visible item visible):

```
    if (mListView != null) {
        int firstVisible = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
                - mListView.getHeaderViewsCount();
        int lastVisible = mListView.getLastVisiblePosition()
                - mListView.getHeaderViewsCount();

        View child = mListView.getChildAt(lastVisible
                - firstVisible);
        int offset = child.getTop() + child.getMeasuredHeight()
                - mListView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (offset > 0) {
            mListView.smoothScrollBy(offset, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works great! Although I should mention an edge case that requires a code change: you have to call mListView.post( new Runnable() { public void run() { (the code above); } ) } ); This handles the case where you're modifying the last child's height (thus making the ListView's contents taller). Posting a runnable gives the ListView a chance to update itself before you try to scroll to the new bottom of the list.

Comment: Unfortunately there's an internal cap to the amount that `ListView.smoothScrollBy` will scroll. That's because internally it simulates a user fling. Using this method to scroll 10 screens worth of items results in scrolling by only a few screens.

Answer (score 2):

I have a shorter and, in my opinion, better solution to do this : ListView requestChildRectangleOnScreen method is designed for it.

The answer above ensures that the item will be displayed, but sometimes it will be displayed partly (ie. when it is at the bottom of the screen). The code below ensures that the whole item will be displayed and that the view will scroll only the necessary zone :

```
    private void ensureVisible(ListView parent, View view) {
    Rect rect = new Rect(view.getLeft(), view.getTop(), view.getRight(), view.getBottom());
    parent.requestChildRectangleOnScreen(view, rect, false);
}
```

Comment: If you use API 8 or later, ListView smoothScrollToPosition() method is even smarter solution.

Comment: The problem with Yves' answer is that this `View` doesn't necessarily exist... if it's not visible, `ListView` will most probably have discarded it. Indeed, `smoothScrollToPosition` is the good answer here.