# android listview first visible position

Tags: android, listview

How can I change the first visible item in a list view (I searched a method such as setFirstVisiblePosition) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988916/ensure-visible-on-android-listview).

Comment: How did you solved that? I wanna scroll the clicked expandableItem to the first visible position of the list.

Answer (score 16):

> ```
> ListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()
> ```
>
> Returns the position within the
>   adapter's data set for the first item
>   displayed on screen. Once you have the
>   position, you can alter the item at
>   that position in your adapter.

Presume my Adapter is binding a String[] to a ListView. I can use `getFirstVisiblePosition()` method on the listview instance, which will return the index/position of the first visible item, I can then change my String item at the "index"th position and alter the list.

Comment: I do not understood your explanation. I wanna scroll the clicked expandableItem to the first visible position of the expandableList. Did you know how to do that?